# Pattern matching in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working on a Haskell project and I have some trouble with this code snippet:

```
buildTowers :: [Int] -> Int ->[[Bool]]
buildTowers [x] max = (buildBoolList x max) :[]
buildTowers (x:xs) max = (buildBoolList x max):buildTowers xs max
```

I get this error: Non exhausting pattern matches, but for me it seems as everthing is covered. Do you know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't matching the empty list: `buildTowers []`

Comment: Yet another reason to use `-Wall`: it would have pointer out the definition without type signatures, spotting the typo.

Comment: This is only tangentially related to your problem, but: why make the base case `[x]` instead of `[]`?

Comment: Thank you very much sometimes a typo can be your worst enemy...

Answer (score 1):

As @Reid Barton already pointed out in the comments, you are missing to match the empty list. I'd further go with @Daniel Wagners suggestion, merging both in this community answer so the question can be closed.